# GridLayout doesn't respect the given number of rows and columns

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display a grid of coloured JLabels inside a JPanel. I created a custom class PixelMatrix which extends JPanel and I populated it with a custom class Pixel which extends JLabel.
The problem is: when I put my Pixel objects inside my GridLayout in the PixelMatrix object, I don't get the number of rows and columns I desire.

This is my Pixel class:

```
public class Pixel extends JLabel{

    private Color color = null;
    private int dimension;
    
    public Pixel(Color c, int dim) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dim, dim));
        this.dimension = dim;
        this.color = c;
        this.setBackground(color);
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }
    
    public Pixel(int dim) {
        this(new Color(0x000000), dim);
    }
    
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    
    public void setColor(Color c) {
        color = c;
    }
}
```

This is my PixelMatrix class:

```
public class PixelMatrix extends JPanel{

    private int resolution;
    private Pixel[][] pixels = null;
    private GridLayout layout;
    
    public PixelMatrix(int res) {
        resolution = res;
        layout = new GridLayout(0, res);
        
        pixels = new Pixel[res][res];
        for(int x = 0; x < res; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < res; y++) {
                pixels[x][y] = new Pixel(50);
                this.add(pixels[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class is use to display all the stuff:

```
public class EditorPanel extends JPanel{

    private BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenu settingsMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
    private JMenu sizeSubMenu = new JMenu("Size"); 
    private JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    private JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open...");
    private JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem size6x6Item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("6 x 6", true);
    private JRadioButtonMenuItem size8x8Item = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("8 x 8");
    private ButtonGroup sizeButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private PixelMatrix matrix = new PixelMatrix(6);
    
    public EditorPanel() {
        setup();
    }
    
    private void setup() {
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        
        sizeButtonGroup.add(size6x6Item);
        sizeSubMenu.add(size6x6Item);
        sizeButtonGroup.add(size8x8Item);
        sizeSubMenu.add(size8x8Item);
        settingsMenu.add(sizeSubMenu);
        
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(settingsMenu);
        
        this.setLayout(layout);
        this.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        this.add(matrix, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

And this is what I get. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Wfd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a custom class PixelMatrix which extends JPanel

```
layout = new GridLayout(0, res);
```

That doesn't do anything. That just creates a variable.

The default layout manager is the `FlowLayout`, and that hasn't been changed. The components flow one after another and wrap to the next line.

You need to set the layout of the panel if you want to use a `GridLayout`.

So you could do:

```
layout = new GridLayout(0, res);
setLayout( layout );
```

Or, even easier don't bother to use a variable:

```
setLayout( new GridLayout(0, res) );
```

Also, why would you call the variable "resolution". That term is normally used for the "resolution of your screen in terms of pixels". A layout has nothing to do with resolution. You area attempting to specify the "columns" in the grid, that would be a better variable name.

Comment: I created the layout but I forgot to set it, this is so embarassing :) Thank you!